# How to solve this error.Command Phase ScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code?

Tags: swift5

I remove PaymentGateway pods like- Paypal and Paypalcheckout from own project then I face these issue,I tried to resolve issue but no anyone method properly work in this case I Tried to solve through pod updation, excluding artichecture both project and pods file, remove drive data and remove Podfile lock but results doesn't satifactory
.
Please help to solve this error?